# Link to resources inside WebView - iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, resources, hyperlink, webview

I have a webview in my iPhone application, and I also have some html files inside my Resources folder. When my app loads, I load in a page from my resources into my webview. But , I need to make links inside my webview that point to some other resources (For example, images, or other html files). Just doing a relative link doesn't work:

```
<a href="OtherPage.html">Doesn't work</a>
```

Comment: Do you mind giving a full example of the code that works? Reading this page thoroughly, I'm still a bit confused about how to put it all together properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you load those resources, you need to set the base URL. You can do this using the method:

```
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

...where baseURL would be the file URL of your resources folder.

Comment: Thanks - but I will accept my answer not yours because it actually solves my problem (with your help). Thanks!

Comment: You can still do it in 3.0. See jdandrea's answer.

Answer (score 26):

Apparently there's a bit of a gotcha according to the [iPhone SDK Release Notes for iPhone OS 3.0](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/releasenotes/General/RN-iPhoneSDK-3/index.html):

> **Issue:** UIWebView can't load local resources in apps built against 3.0.
>
> When using `[UIWebView
>   loadHTMLString:baseURL:]`, the HTML
>   string should not refer to local
>   resources with the `file://` scheme.
>   Instead, pass in `NULL` or a `file://`
>   URL for `baseURL:`, or include the
>   resources directly in the HTML with
>   `<style>` and `<script>` tags.

Fair enough. But passing in a standard-issue `file://` URL for `baseURL` doesn't quite work. However ... it turns out that, if you change `/` to `//` and spaces to `%20`, you will be set! (Using `%20` makes a lot of sense, but the double-slash part caught me by surprise.)

Let's say you already have `NSString *markup` set up. Here's all you do. (I've wrapped the code here for readability. You may wish to refactor/adjust to taste.)

```
 NSString *resourcePath = [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"//"]
     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
 [webView loadHTMLString:markup baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file:/%@//", resourcePath]]];
```

So long as your CSS, JavaScript and images are referred to by filename alone, this should do the trick in iPhone OS 3.0 where `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` is concerned!

Comment: works awesome thanks for posting... this should be the right answer

Comment: Y'know … now that I look at what I wrote again, I wonder if I made a faux pas by using "file:/%@//" instead of "file://%@/" ? That might be the inadvertent source of the / to // requirement, in which case it's only a matter of handling spaces, which is standard-issue S/G/HTML stuff. Thoughts? (It has been a while, so if I'm forgetting my own logic here, feel free to correct me - ha!)

Comment: Had the same problem just now in iOS 4.2. Local images were not displayed. Then I ended up formatting my URL like this (quadruple slashes!) and it works: "file:////Users//iDeveloper//Library//Application%20Support//iPhone%20Simulator//4.2//Applications//9706B7FE-4FAC-4FB0-9DA4-C07F322D4AC1//TestBrowser.app//Data//HTML//English//". Using the "correct" syntax with one slash in the path and two slashes for "file://" does NOT work. Thank You a lot!

Answer (score 7):

I fixed it: I used this for the BaseURL like August said:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
```

Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't appear to work in iPhone OS 3.0. See my other post for a slight modification!

Answer (score 3):

This code would return a string with the URL of a file named "OtherPage.html" in your bundle's resources directory.

```
[[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"OtherPage" ofType:@"html"]] absoluteString]
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. My HTML files were in sub-folders (not groups) in my project. My html page is called page01 and the sub-folder is html:

```
NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString *pathToHtml = @"html";
NSURL *baseURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:pathToHtml isDirectory:YES];

NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]    
                             pathForResource:@"page01" ofType:@"html"                                                               
                             inDirectory:@"html"] 
                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try loading OtherPage.html first. If you can't then it's not there, and you've missed some part of adding it to the project.  If you can, then there may just be a typo in the link, or the baseURL could be incorrect, as stated by August.  When I created an html file with images in it that were in the resource file, it worked fine just using

```
<img src="file.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how Phonegap does it. [Here's their tutorial on local resources on the iPhone](http://phonegap.pbwiki.com/Building+A+Self-Contained+Application+(iPhone)). Step 11 might be what you're neglecting.

Comment: No, I checked all the steps and I did all of them. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it does have something to do with the baseurl: when I load the resources, I use this line:

```
[webView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

see at the end, it says baseURL: "". If I take this out, it doesn't work (crashes), but I don't know the path to my resources. If somebody does.....?

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that js files were not included in the bundle. Be sure to check that.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here 3.5 years later :) ... tried Michael Gaylord's suggestion above exactly, but it didn't work in sims for 5.0, 5.1, 6.0, 6.1 - nor in real devices running same. **However** this SO clarification on where resources are bundled ( [Where is build output going?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341496/where-is-build-output-going/5342176#5342176) ) helped make it work for me like this:

1. create a Finder folder in the project ( as Michael suggests - and I also did NOT try 'group')
2. put your html in that folder using Finder
3. in Xcode use *file* -> *add files to project*
4. Make sure the project recognizes that it should be in the bundle by:

   5. Right click on main project target in *Navigator* window,
   6. make sure TARGETS is selected, the *Build Phases* tab,
   7. Click the *Copy Bundle Resources* triangle thingy |>
   8. And - **here's what's different from Michael's**  - It should already show your html file AND the path.  (Perhaps the XCoders have improved the add files AI :)

So all I had to do was copy - paste Michael's code above *verbatum* and change this one line:

```
                     inDirectory:@"html"]
```

to:

```
                     inDirectory:nil]
```

and ***Shaazam*** ! it worked :)