# Is there a way to capture all NSURLRequests while loading a html-page?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlprotocol

To be specific: If I want download a html-page, there are many requests to image, music, js, etc, which I cannot handle by UIWebView delegates.

To be more specific: I'm interested in handling of ajax-requests! I have tried to implement ajax-handler by injecting javascript in every loaded html-page (source: [UIWebViewDelegate not monitoring XMLHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353278/uiwebviewdelegate-not-monitoring-xmlhttprequest)), but this is not working (iOS 5.1.1).

I think there are solution by implementing subclass of NSURLProtocol (simple proxy), but I dont know how.

Please help!

Comment: There is demo for you, the OnionBrowser: click [here](https://github.com/mtigas/iOS-OnionBrowser/blob/master/OnionBrowser/ProxyURLProtocol.m) I think it is helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do something very similar and managed to get it working by implementing a NSURLProtocol and forcing the response to load a local json file.

You can see the full implementation here :

[How to mock AJAX call with NSURLProtocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224071/how-to-mock-ajax-call-with-nsurlprotocol/15234787#15234787)