# Calling an instance method when subclassing NSURLProtocol

Tags: objective-c, class, instance, nsurlprotocol

So I've had to subclass NSURLProtocol because I am using a UIWebView and want to intercept ajax calls which works fine as per [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11624391/196420). I have to get the data from the request from `+ (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request` which causes a problem, I now need to call instance methods to do things with the data, but I can't because it's a class method.

How could I call an instance method based on the contents of what is in the request?

Comment: Do these methods you need to call need to access instance variables or can you refactor those methods so they are in turn class methods?

Comment: Yeah they do unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call instance methods from a class method without having an instance first. This is true for all object-oriented systems, AFAIK. After all, the instance methods (usually) use data that the class method cannot have. Imagine an object with a property `name`, and you now have one thousand objects with different names. How should the class method know which `name` to use?

So you need to find a way to somehow query instances of your class based on your request, or find a way to get at the information in a way that does not involve instance variables (if a method doesn't use instance variable you can turn it into a class method or even C function). There are many different ways to solve the "query problem", which to chose is highly dependent on your design and even taste.

Answer (score 0):

canInitWithRequest: shouldn't do any work whatsoever, it should just respond with "YES" or "NO". "startLoading" is where you do the work.