# UIWebView: track changes of dynamic content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, change-tracking

I'm loading a dynamic HTML page that includes AJAX into an UIWebView. The content of the already loaded HTML page might change during time. None of the UIWebViewDelegate Methods get called if that happens. How can I find out if the content changed?

I'm aware of the solution to just use a timer to periodically track changes of the displayed HTML content. But I would very much prefer to get notified if the content changed. How could I achieve this?

Comment: possible solution already [here][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5353278/1403732

Comment: This definitely goes into the right direction. The problem is that it catches only the outgoing requests but not the fact if the content changes in response to those requests. If I'm right.