# Intercept Ajax calls in UIWebview - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ajax, ipad, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a `UIWebView` in my application. The website I am loading uses `Ajax` for making service calls.

I want to intercept `Ajax` calls made by the `web content` inside the `UIWebview`.

Is there anyway this can be achieved?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5353278/1403732