# Loading a UIWebview with a local HTML file from a nested folder structure

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

Specifically, I have a folder structure that looks like the below:

- about (main folder)

  - css  (this sub-folder contains the css files)
  - img  (this sub-folder contains the img files)
  - js (this sub-folder contains the js files)
  - page (this subfolder contains the index.html file)

If I click on the index.html file from a normal computer browser, everything works as expected.

However, I am trying to load this index.html into a `UIWebView`.

So far, what I've done is I dragged the "about" folder to XCode and copied it there as I would any other file.  Then I tried the following code:

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
[webView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:baseURL];
```

The webview loads the index.html, however it doesnt load the images/css/js, as I presume it can't find them within the folder structure.

Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: I don't think folder structures are carried over to the iOS app binary. You'll need unique filenames.

Comment: all files that you submit your application, including those contained in sub folders, are placed in the root directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

oops, I actually found the answer here:  [Load resources from relative path using local html in uiwebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420925/load-resources-from-relative-path-using-local-html-in-uiwebview)

I was able to use the actual folder structure as is with the following code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"/about/page"]];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `images/css/js` use only `sample.js`.