# custom fonts in uiwebview but not in app bundle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

We have a web app that basically is a text editor with 100 fonts available via @font-face.

We are creating an iOS app that syncs with this (we had no problems with the Android app).

The iOS app has a menu and UIWebviews that load locally stored data. We want to have the same css with @font-face available to the webview but it doesn't need to be available to the rest of the app.

The problem with adding fonts to info.plist is that when you get past 50-60 ttfs, the app crashes.

Is there a way to do this with just html/css/js and not have to involve the app bundle?

(This needs to work offline within the app itself).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just bundle the fonts as plain files without registering them in a property list, then they will be available locally to html/css/js files in the same bundle, or directly via urls. See [this question for examples with other types of web files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8436281/204883).