# How to make Xcode and Javascript Play Nice?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, xcode, d3.js

**Question 1:**

I am trying to use [this D3 example](http://bl.ocks.org/marufbd/7191340) in Xcode. I have my UIWebView set up and working well, but the Javascript is not. I believe it has something to do with the code referencing files on the server on which it was hosted.  **How can I reference the files with Javascript inside Xcode? More specifically, what filepath should I use?**

For example, The `main.html` file references a certain `D3.chart.js` by saying  `require ['d3.chart.js']`, will this work in Xcode?

Comment: Please limit yourself to asking *one* question per, uh, question.  This is per SO guidelines.

Comment: @Madbreaks: sorry about that, fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your JavaScript files are hosted somewhere you'd simply point at that location, just like on any other web page.  If though you're bundling the JS with your app, you'll want to included them by adding a copy files build phase.  At that point you can load them using `fileURLWithPath` [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420925/load-resources-from-relative-path-using-local-html-in-uiwebview).