# How to load local (Document directory) html into webview in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios7, uiwebview

I would like to load html files, which are downloaded into document folder. First page is loaded ok, but links to second page not works and images not work too. I am using this code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"index.htm"];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[pruvodceWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Is there any reason, why webview do this? Thank you

Comment: Its problem of html file not iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have HTML source but not images
Instead of

```
[pruvodceWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

You should define baseURL. If your images are in documents directory

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[pruvodceWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

Or provide path to images if they have relative path

```
[pruvodceWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString@"http://yourSiteHere.com/"]];
```

Check out this: 
[Load resources from relative path using local html in uiwebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420925/load-resources-from-relative-path-using-local-html-in-uiwebview)