# Unwrapping an Optional value Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am to load html file in my webview. The files contain references to `/css` and `/images` sub directories. So, I found the following from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26202983/1304700).

```
    let path: String? = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Ace-VetBolus", ofType: "html", inDirectory: "HTMLFiles")
    let requestURL = NSURL(string:path!);
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL:requestURL!);

    web1.loadRequest(request)
```

And I cannot resolve this issue: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` at the second line.

Comment: As I mentioned at the second line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use NSBundle method URLForResource:

```
if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Ace-VetBolus", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "HTMLFiles") {
    let requestURL = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    web1.loadRequest(requestURL)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `!` forcefully unwraps a value, so if it's `nil`, you're going to get a fatal error as you see.

You want to use an `if let` statement or a `guard` statement.

```
let path: String? = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Ace-VetBolus", ofType: "html", inDirectory: "HTMLFiles")
if let unwrappedPath = path {
    let requestURL = NSURL(string: unwrappedPath)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL)

    web1.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Using `guard` in Swift 2 functions like so:

```
let path: String? = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Ace-VetBolus", ofType: "html", inDirectory: "HTMLFiles")
guard let unwrappedPath = path else {
    return // or handle fail case some other way
}
let requestURL = NSURL(string: unwrappedPath)
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
web1.loadRequest(request)
```

Biggest different is the `guard` pattern allows you to keep the unwrapped variable in the same scope, while `if let` creates a new scope.

Comment: NSURL(string:) it is only for web links, not for local resources. When creating NSURL for local file resources you need to use init(fileURLWithPath path: String). https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/initFileURLWithPath:

Comment: Fair enough, I was just looking at the specific question, not the underlying APIs. :)

Comment: No no, I understood your comment, I am saying I merely wrapped it naively in an if let assuming that the OP was using an API correctly. I will look closer next time. :)