# Create a file in a standard position to read it in an html page

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift, path

I want to write a Javascript in a standard location and connect this file to a page html.

Write: (using Swift 1.2)

```
let path = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "foo.js"
    var error: NSError?
    text = "12345"
    text.writeToFile(path, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)
```

html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="path/foo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <p> Use Foo </p>

</body>
```

Which path i can use?

Comment: you can use javscript in the above approach , but while setting url to to webview user `relativetopath:` as javascript file location

Comment: or you can try like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34206714/1142743