# Open image in webview (when image and css store in a local storage)

Tags: ios, swift, webview

i can get html data from sqlite database .

```
let html = "<htmll>
...
...
<img src="Documents/datadb/DestinationGuide/Images/Destination-Guide.png">
...
</html>"
 webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
```

Image store in this path

```
Documents/datadb/DestinationGuide/Images/Destination-Guide.png
```

It can not load in webview.

I think i want to give full path like application name after add this .

How to scan html code and replace `src` and `href`

Already try this :

```
~/Documents/datadb/DestinationGuide/Images/Destination-Guide.png
/Documents/datadb/DestinationGuide/Images/Destination-Guide.png
/DestinationGuide/Images/Destination-Guide.png
/DestinationGuide/Images/Destination-Guide.png
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420925/load-resources-from-relative-path-using-local-html-in-uiwebview

Comment: i can get data from sqlite database in String formate . i have no html file. database and image folder  download every time when user login and put in document folder .

Comment: @HarshilKotecha In string format means the URL like `Documents/datadb/DestinationGuide/Images/Destination-Guide.png`, right ?

Comment: no i can get full html code in string formate not only URL

Comment: when i pass html after print Log output like this .  <img src=\"/Documents/datadb/DestinationGuide/Images/Destination-Guide@3x.png\" alt=\"\" />

Comment: @HarshilKotecha There is one way if you able to remove `/Documents/` from the image src, Can you done that? Means path only need to be `datadb/DestinationGuide/Images/Destination-Guide.png`

Comment: yes sure.  i able to do this

Comment: i try this one still facing issue . <img src=\"datadb/DestinationGuide/Images/Destination-Guide.png\" alt=\"\" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save this html at `DocumentDirectory` as `HTML` file and then load that file `webView`. Try something like this way.

```
let html = "<html><img src=\"datadb/DestinationGuide/Images/Destination-Guide.png\"/> </html>"
//Save this html in `DocumentDirectory`
let saveHTML = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("sample.html")
try? html.data(using: .utf8)!.write(to: saveHTML)
//Now load this `sample.html` file in webView
webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: saveHTML))
```

Comment: i also thinking like this just a minute i test this one :D