# How to set file-path in ViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, webview, uiviewcontroller

This is my project structure:

[image: image 0]

I have 2 different **View Controllers** (`GameViewController,` `TaskViewController`). Both of them should be able to show a `web view` to the user.

- The **web view** for **GameViewController** should load the file `www/game/index.html`
- The **web view** for **TaskViewController** should load the file `www/task/index.html`

Adding the web view is quiet easy. But how can I specific the right path?

This was what I've tried inside the `GameViewController`:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "www/game") // not working

let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "game") // not working

let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "myApplication/www/game") // not working
```

How can I set the path for the files (with the same names [`index.html`] ) the right way?

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have to add the HTML files as "folder references" to your project, otherwise all files will be copied to the same directory in the application bundle. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420925/load-resources-from-relative-path-using-local-html-in-uiwebview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the files with references selected , suppose I have a folder named **pp** inside it there is a **premium.txt** when I drag it to Xcode selected **create folder references** and reference it easily with subdirectory, the folder will have a blue color

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've deleted my html-files and dragged them again into the folders. I've also enabled "create folder reference" but using this code: `let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "game")` will not work either.

Comment: game folder must contain index.html directly without inner subdirectories before you drag the folder to Xcode ????