# .css and .js files are not being found by UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, xcode, uiwebview

I have added an `.html`, two `.js` and one `.css` file in my project and I have used following code with UIWebView for accessing the .html file

```
[web1 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                           [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]

pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO]]];
```

Where web1 is my UIWebView and it is synthesized. Now when I open that page, it is without any CSS, just lines and links in order and no decoration.

And also when I click on any link, it does not show me my expected results, because .js is not working (or I should say, they are not being found by xcode, though I have added them with normal files as well as with frameworks).

Comment: How did you include the css and js files in the html file? What do you mean with "not found by Xcode"?

Comment: i have add css and java file like this 
<head>
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="css/layout.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="java/script.js"></script>

i have try this also 

<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="layout.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

i mean xcode don;t run js and css file just run the html file without css and js..

Comment: @ranakhan Please be a little more polite. People are just trying to help. Maybe `d4Rk` needed to go away for, whatever reasons, making him not able to answer right now. Please be patient ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following things:

- did you properly add the files to your projects resources?
- are they included in your targets build phases?

If you are sure about this, and it's still not working, I would recommend to try the following (which was working for me in the past)

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"index" withExtension:@"html"];
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this answers, I think they may point you in the right direction:

[UIWebView doesn't load external Javascript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606272/uiwebview-doesnt-load-external-javascript-file)

[iPhone UIWebView local resources using Javascript and handling onorientationChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843820/iphone-uiwebview-local-resources-using-javascript-and-handling-onorientationchan/851333#851333)