# How to embed local images in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

Is there an easy way to embed local images in an UIWebView? For example, I would want to embed an logo.png image in the UIWebView, which I've added to the Resources folder in Xcode. Would I simply add an `img` HTML tag for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using HTML and Local Images Within UIWebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747407/using-html-and-local-images-within-uiwebview)

Comment: you may refer to my answer on this post, hope it work for you [ http://stackoverflow.com/a/43011715/1316779 ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43011715/1316779)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

yes it's very simple but, for others, remember to put "file://" at the beginning of your path

for example:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"png"];
[myWebView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><img src=\"file://%@\"></body></html>",path] baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: Along the same line as this answer, but you folks might appreciate this link: http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/uiwebview-revisited

Comment: Don't work for me in swift `let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("txtIcon", ofType: "png")` -->  `bodyNew = "<a href=\"xxxxx\" style=\"text-decoration:none\"><img src=\"file://\(path!)\" alt=\"xxxxxx\" width=\"309\" height=\"309\"/><br><pre>     \(attachmentName)</pre></a><br><br><br>"`