# How to refer a local image file from UIWebView's HTML on iPhone?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I would like to use `<img src="`**`temp.jpg`**`" />` in my UIWebView's HTML.
How can I refer to a local file named **`temp.jpg`** to save precious loading time?

Of course the obvious choice would be `<img src="`**`.\temp.jpg`**`" />` but I have no idea where my root is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSURL *url=[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL];
[webView loadHTMLString:string baseURL:url];
```

This let's the root be the app's main bundle.

Answer (score 9):

This will create a URL object that contains the location of your file on disk. You can then use this to output a valid `file://` URL string that can be used within `img` tags.

```
NSURL* fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"temp" withExtension:@"jpg"];

NSLog(@"<img src=\"%@\" />", fileURL.absoluteString);
```

Comment: It should be URLForResource: withExtension:  instead of pathForResource, then you don't need the second line

Answer (score 2):

I was searching a lot  for a solution and found the following which
in my case working fine, I have a local HTML string and a local image
I convert the image into base 64

you may use this website to convert image to base64 encoding

[Converter](https://www.base64-image.de/)

and rewrite the HTML string to have the base64 image in the image tag like the following

```
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="Red dot" >
```

for Testing the result tye the following Online HTML editor

[W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_default)

hope it will help for others or maybe get a better solution, best of luck

Answer (score 0):

> I have no idea where my root is...

`UIWebView` looks up files relative to the HTML file you loaded in it. So perhaps it will be your app bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to construct a base64image string from your local file in the swift code, and pass this string to your webview. you can render these base 64 strings by passing them to an img html tag directly. In my use case I needed to embed this image tag an HTML attributedString with a document type of html and render this html string within an actual UILabel ... I'll post some example code here, you may need to play around it, and you'd just pass the string to your webview instead -

```
let base64EncodedImage = UIImage.init(named: “my_image”).jpegData(compressionQuality: .leastNonzeroMagnitude)?.base64EncodedString()

let htmlString: String = "<div style='font-size:15px;display:inline;'> <b>hello internet</b> <img src='data:image/jpg;base64,\(base64image)' /> </div>"

let attributedText = try? NSMutableAttributedString(
    data: data,
    options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
              .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
    documentAttributes: nil
)

let label: UILabel = .init()

label.attributedText = attributedText
```