# How can i add image in HTML content in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

i want to add the image with webview content coming from the web service. please see the  below image i want to do like this. i have no idea how to do this?[image]

i want to add the horizontal separator in both the side of the title. i have added the title but no idea how to add separator on both the side of title.

```
NSString *strVision=[[dict valueForKey:@"errResult"] valueForKey:@"Vission"];

NSString *strmission=[[dict valueForKey:@"errResult"]valueForKey:@"mission"];

NSString *strVM = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<b>%@</b><br>%@<br><br><b>%@</b><br>%@",@"Vision",strVision,Mission",strmission];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try With this

```
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"png"];
    [myWebView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><img src=\"file://%@\"></body></html>",path] baseURL:nil];
```

Source by:[Stack Over Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808451/how-to-embed-local-images-in-uiwebview)