# load locally stored image in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

My requirement is to load locally stored image in the UIWebView.

My code is as follows:

```
NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSURL *homeIndexUrl = [mainBundle URLForResource:@"web" withExtension:@"html"];
    NSURLRequest *urlReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:homeIndexUrl];
    [self.webView loadRequest:urlReq];
```

My html file is as follows:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <img src=“Initial.png”>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have referred following links but I am not getting my ultimate output

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747407/using-html-and-local-images-within-uiwebview) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808451/how-to-embed-local-images-in-uiwebview)

Comment: where r u storing the image? in the project folder?

Comment: @T_77:Yes I store it in images.xcassets folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This thing worked for me:

The image should not be in the xcassettes.

```
  NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageFileName ofType:imageFileExtension];
 NSString *imgHTMLTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img src=\"file://%@\" />", imagePath];
 NSURL *Url = [mainBundle URLForResource:@"img_icon" withExtension:@"png"];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:imgHTMLTag baseURL:Url];
```

Comment: you should keep the image in your project folder ,but not in the xcassets