# Difficulties in detecting touch while animating an imageview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I am trying to animate an image using following code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:40];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0);
CGAffineTransform moveRight = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
CGAffineTransform firstHalf = CGAffineTransformConcat(rotate, moveRight);
CGAffineTransform zoomIn = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2,2);

CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(zoomIn, firstHalf);
fimage.transform = transform;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I have UIScrollView which has one subview UIImageView and fimage is that UIImageView. But when i try to detect the touch on it i am not able to do that. Can any one help me? Is is possible to detect touches on UIScrollView.

The main application is to display images in panning and when user clicks on it the web page containing that image should be loaded in next web view.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and it seems to be working without hiccups. It is likely that the image view object has its `userInteractionEnabled` set to `NO`. Set it to `YES` to make touches work.

Check [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747407/using-html-and-local-images-within-uiwebview) to see how you can load images in `UIWebView` object. As for panning, you should try out the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` if you aren't already.