# How can i insert an image inside html code?

Tags: iphone, html, css, ios, uiwebview

i need to add a background image to a phone number that is contained inside an HTML code that i load into a UIWebView

```
NSString *stringToReplace = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<a style=\"color:white; background-color:#707070; text-decoration:none\" href=\"compose://%@\">%@</a>",substring,substring];
    newString = [newString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:substring withString:stringToReplace];
```

I've managed to change the background color, but instead i need to put an image as background.
The main goal is to make a lightGray Background with rounded corners behind the phone number.

I've found what was the problem
[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747407/using-html-and-local-images-within-uiwebview)

Thanks,

Comment: http://www.google.hu/search?q=html+background+image

Answer (score 0):

i dont really undderstand your code, maybe you should use [css background images](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp):

```
background: #afdafd    url('path...');
          /*def.color. back.img.*/  

<a style=\"color:white; background:#707070 url('/images/rounded-corner.png'); text-decoration:none\" href=\"compose://%@\">%@</a>
```

Comment: I've tried to add an image like that but it doesn't load. What path should i specify for my image?

Comment: I only see the gray background and no image

Comment: the path pointing to the image. try to open the image into the browser and use the path in the adress bar.

Comment: this is an iPhone app and i've tried to put the path but there is no image showed.