# iPhone: Showing HTML like content (help page) with scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit

I am currently designing a help page for my iPhone app using interface builder.  IB seems lacking in terms of designing content that is larger than one page.  I may want to put an image or two in between content to make the help more visually appealing and easier to understand. Currently I have one large label that flows off the screen which doesnt scroll.

So what is the best method to achieve a half decent help page, with basic text and images and scrolling.  Am I best off simply creating a web page and embedding it in the app somehow then displaying it in a web control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UIWebView` will handle HTML content given to it in a string.

If you want to load local images in the UIWebview, refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747407/using-html-and-local-images-within-uiwebview):

Define path using:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

Then you can access the image using the standard

```
<img src="myimage.png">
```

[This link](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/uiwebview-revisited) is the original page.

Comment: Any idea how I'd load local images in too?

Comment: Awesome thanks, P.s. I have tried this but the image doesnt load... Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or how I can debug this?

Comment: Are you using a .png file? Perhaps the second link that I added will help. It suggests putting your code in viewWillAppear, if you haven't done that.

Comment: Yes it is a png file, does that matter?

Comment: No its good because my sample code references a png file. Did the link help?

Comment: I re read your question and the link and it solved my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should look at Facebook's Three20 library ( http://three20.info ) and its TTStyledLabel. It can handle HTML-like formatting. If you need content larger thatn one page, you should consider using UIWebView for that.

Answer (score 1):

Put your text label inside a UIScrollView and set it's `lineBreakMode` to `UILineBreakModeWordWrap`:

```
textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. I have a Scroll View with two labels inside, one heading and one with the content set to 0 lines and word wrap...