# How to show the image in html in the iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

iOS Simulator Screen shot 21-Jun-2013 2.57.02 PM.png[image]

Comment: What? This is incomprehensible...

Comment: @H2CO3-he is asking that how to show the images in the html pages

Comment: Google around. As @H2CO3 said, this is incomprehensible. Check this link out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169763/how-to-load-images-with-html-file-in-uiwebview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747407/using-html-and-local-images-within-uiwebview

Comment: +1 for Question I think this is a valid and usefull question

Comment: All the image links are dead. This question isn't going to be useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your `HTML` is in resource directory? If yes, then remove `absolute/relative` image path from `<img>` tag in your `.html` file. Only use the image name, and also check that your image must be in your `resource` directory.

Comment: +1 for good answer and recogning the problem

Comment: Is this solved your problem?

Comment: <img src="images/img_1.png" width="135" height="135" alt="">

Comment: prateek <img src="images/img_1.png" width="135" height="135" alt="">   ka path hai how can manage the path

Comment: prateek <img src="images/img_1.png" width="135" height="135" alt=""> how to set the image path hai how can manage the path

Comment: Do this <img src="img_1.png" width="135" height="135" alt="">