# Display image from camera within UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I have iPhone Application that use web view, and I run iPhone camera from the Application and get the image, my question is how to get this image back inside the `UIWebView`?

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747407/using-html-and-local-images-within-uiwebview

Comment: do u have image captured from camera?

Comment: add some code as u said put the image in some field of the response

Comment: yes i have the image from the camera

Answer (score 2):

save the image in your local documents folder and load that image in the webview.