# Replacing image URLs in html string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

Hello I have a html string, with  tags for every image.

I can extract the url of every image, but what I want is to save those images in the device, and then replace each one's image url with the corresponding path from my sandbox and then display them via `UIWebView`.

Any ideas how do I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you have the URL for an image, you can save it like this

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL urlWithString:string]];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFile"];
[imageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

To replace the URLs in the HTML string simply use the method

`- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target 
                                        withString:(NSString *)replacement`

Comment: Is there more efficient method, for a lot of images? I have to do that for every image.Besides there is cool way to get images from sandbox in webview - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747407/using-html-and-local-images-within-uiwebview Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I don't think there is. You can always do it in the background and add a loading widget or something if it's required. As for the sandbox thing, if you have the <img src = yourURL>, you proceed as described in that post you linked and you use the method I mentioned to replace yourURL with the name of the image in your project.

Comment: Oh and don't forget to add an extra set of quotes for the filename

Comment: Can UICollectionView help here?

Comment: I haven't used UICollectionView yet, but that's just a way of presenting a set of views. If you think that it better suits your needs, go ahead and use it (iOS 6 only though). It's got nothing to do with saving images to local storage however.

Comment: Vlad just one question. What does NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFile"];
do? Is it directory like Documents/MyFile/ or it's a file like Documents/MyFile.png It's a little bit frustrating. Thanks

Comment: It's the path to your file i.e. Documents/myImage.png. Sorry wasn't too clear on that.

Comment: Thanks, how do I save it to custom directory inside Documents? I have tried  NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyDir/MyFile"]; and it doesn't save it.