# Image Tag in HTML when creating PDF

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf

I am generating a PDF from an HTML string in iOS using the below code.  I appear to be losing any  tags when it creates the PDF.  I have tried both adding src attribute pointing to the file on the device as well as putting base64 image data into the source.

Here I create a UIMarkupTextPrinterFormatter:

```
UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter *fmt = [[UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter alloc]
                                   initWithMarkupText:htmlStringHere];
```

My htmlStringHere value contains:

```
<html><head><style>.testClass{color:yellow;font-weight:bold;}</style></head><body><img src="Icon.png" ></img></body>
```

I then use a custom UIPrintPageRenderer to generate the PDF.  At this point, the image has been lost.  Other html elements are not lost however.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest here whenever you use the UIWebView with HTML string. you have to specify the BASEURL in its second parameter. BASEURL is responsible to load the resources in your HTML string. I think you missed to specify or may be specified wrong.

Please refer this answer for BASEURL

[Using HTML and Local Images Within UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/747644)

[UIWebView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW10)

Hope this will help :)