# UIWebView load on the server HTML, how to load local images?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, uiwebview

Here is loaded HTML code

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"111" ofType:@"jpg"];
NSURLRequest *repuest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.5/index.html"]];
[webView loadRequest:repuest];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Here is the HTML code

```
<img src="111.jpg" />
<hr />
```

Do so the image could not be loaded . In this case, How to make HTML loaded into the picture ?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747407/using-html-and-local-images-within-uiwebview.

Comment: Maybe you need to specify a `baseurl` ?

Comment: No repetition. My HTML is above the server .

Comment: As your html is on server. You need to specify whole path of that image in <img src="">.

Comment: file://localhost/Users/Michael/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/32057AD3-50AE-47EF-AF78-3BF8638EDDE0/UMSAgentExample.app/111.jpg  Replaced this address will not work.

Comment: Use this url file:///localhost/Users/Michael/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/‌​6.1/Applications/32057AD3-50AE-47EF-AF78-3BF8638EDDE0/UMSAgentExample.app/111.jpg

Comment: See these links, it might help you, https://www.google.co.in/search?q=nsnotification%20tutorial&aq=1&oq=nsnotification%20&aqs=chrome.2.57j0l3j62l2.6813j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#sclient=psy-ab&q=showing+local+image+in+webview+%2B+ios+sdk&oq=showing+local+image+in+webview+%2B+ios+sdk&gs_l=serp.3..33i29i30.905876.918861.0.919029.48.44.3.1.1.1.833.5808.22j19j1j0j1j0j1.44.0...1.0...1c.1.11.psy-ab.Ad0lgjuLfbo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=e43e71261d25a34d&biw=1020&bih=582

Answer (score 0):

IF its only one html page without relative links to anything else but the images you can set the base url for the request

that means: all relative urls are considered as relative to this base url

---

BUT if your html uses css/js/html files on the server AND local images, you would need 2 base urls and this isn't possible.

your only bet is to rewrite the html to only use absolute URLS for anything not local and THEN set the base url.

Comment: (Absolute urls are NOT cool but I don't see another non-hackisch way either

Comment: just for reference: you can also dynamically rewrite the html. download it, search for all img tags and replace it)

Comment: Considerable complexity ah .

Answer (score 0):

Ok, This is tried and tested code. Should work for you.

```
NSString *imagePath;
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *path = [bundle bundlePath];
imagePath = [NSBundle pathForResource:@"111" ofType:@"jpg" inDirectory:path];

NSString *fixedURL = [imagePath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
fixedURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@",fixedURL];
NSString *commentHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img src=\"%@\"/>", fixedURL];
NSString *html3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head/><body><div><b>COMMENTS:</b></div>%@</body></html>", commentHtml];

[webView loadHTMLString:html3 baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: I need to load local image in the HTML above .

Comment: Where do you have that local image? In our document directory?

Comment: Pictures in the APP , HTML on the server above .

Comment: In app means? you have added that directly to resource folder or you are fetching that and saving in your documents directory?

Comment: I add a picture directly to the project.