# Segue passing uiimage and open in UIwebview

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I would like to passing a uiimage from one view to another view which contains a uiwebview. So that i can allow easy interaction and gestures on the image.

But i have no idea how to code in the viewdidload method should be used.

Here is my code:

```
//first view
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
 if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showbig"]) {
        bigpic *image = [segue destinationViewController];
        image.bigpicture1 = set11.image;
}

//new view

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:bigpicture1];
    NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.bigpicture loadRequest:requestURL];


}
```

Comment: why you are using web view? use image view instead

Comment: Also, don't call a UIViewController subclass "bigpic". First it should have a capital letter, second it should be descriptive. BigPicViewController. Also, don't call an instance of this "image". At the very least it should be "controller".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the destinationViewController you should have a property `UIImage *imageThatIShouldDisplay`

In your sourceView controller `prepareForSegue` method you will have something like this:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showbig"]) {
        YourDestiantionVC *vc = (YourDestiantionVC*)[segue destinationViewController];
        vc.imageThatIShouldDisplay = set1.image;
}
```

In your destiantion view controller `viewDidLoad` method you will have:

```
if(self.imageThatIShouldDisplay != nil) {
 imageViewThatHandlesImageDisplay.image = self.imageThatIShouldDisplay;
}
else { 
 imageViewThatHandlesImageDisplay.image = [UIImage imageWithName:@"my_image_placeholder.png"]; // in case you want a placeholder.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the image from your bundle to load it into the UIWebView since a UIImage can't be loaded directly into a UIWebView.

[Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747407/using-html-and-local-images-within-uiwebview)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.bigpicture.image = bigpicture1;

}
```

as i think