# implement touch on html and bind in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I want to load a html file with an iPad application, but in the html file there is an image, and that image has a touch event. When I load the html file with webview the image does not appear. Why is that?

I am using code :

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"2line1" ofType:@"html"];
NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile];
[webView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURLURLWithString:@""]];
```

Comment: If it's a local image, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747407/using-html-and-local-images-within-uiwebview

Answer (score 0):

Try This way,

```
  htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat = @"<p><img src='https://yourpath/images/image.png'></p>";
     [yourwebview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```