# Is it possible to integrate a podcast or a youtube channel into a mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I have a business app and I would like to give people more content by integrating a podcast or a youtube channel right into my app.

So when a new show episode is available, it would somehow be also available on my app.
Is that possible to accomplish?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Would using a webpage element like UIWebView be a possible solution? Or have a look at: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: @shadowhorst yes I am open to doing it with UIWebView for the iOS apps. How would it be possible?

Comment: You can load local html files with UIWebView - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747407/using-html-and-local-images-within-uiwebview. Another way would be Apples Multimedia Framework. Have a look at my first comments link.

Comment: @shadowhorst yeah I get the part of getting it to be HTML files. But how do I actually get latest episodes automatically? Is there a common rss-ish practice for this? I guess every time the app screen would load, I would pull the latest episodes?

Comment: You have to ask some kind of web service for new data and download it, if needed. Youtube has a huge API for their own data, having a look at that might help.

Comment: [`Apple search API`](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html#searchexamples) to search content on iTunes including podcasts. The format for the response looks like a JSON. However afaik, other podcasts are RSS feeds so you can access them as webservice and parse using XML parsers in iOS (open source available https://github.com/kballard/feedparser)