# Load Image from UIwebview fail

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am using Webview to load a image file stored in my app Library Directory, first i tried use resourcePath, and bundle path

```
NSString * html = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<img src=\"file://%@\"/>", filename];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:newhtml  baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
```

the problem is no matter what i set in the baseUrl, i can not load the image correctly , i also tried filePath:

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:newhtml  baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] filePath]]];
```

but if i set the absolute path of the image file in the html , all the things is ok, i wonder why?

Comment: hint: NSLog the resulting html string, and see why.

Comment: i got the wrong file name in html.. it is ok if i put the image dir correctly into the baseURL:
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/ImageCache"];

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this post: [Using HTML and Local Images Within UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747407/using-html-and-local-images-within-uiwebview)

The top answer clearly said that using file: paths to refer to images does not work with UIWebView.

All you need to do is to pass the basepath. Example:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

Then just need to reference it like this: `<img src="myimage.png">`

Comment: i see the post , but it is no good for me. in my case, my image files was stored in the bundle path , it stored in ./Library/Caches/

Comment: did u try removing the file keyword? because the baseURL will deal with it.

Comment: thanks , the issue is that the file name in html and the dir are not same..., anyway , the answer help,thanks