# How to display local image on a UIWebView with help of html code?

Tags: html, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to display local image onto the `UIWebView`. This web view is generated with HTML code locally. I am using the following code:

```
[htmlPage appendStringWithFormat:@"< img src=\"%@\" alt=\"image\" height=\"100\" 

width=\"100\"/>",[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myImage" ofType:@"png"];
```

Comment: Look at this question: [Using HTML and Local Images Within UIWebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747407/using-html-and-local-images-within-uiwebview)

Answer (score 2):

You need to load your HTML into the webview with

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

Then your HTML should reference the image like so:

```
body {
    background-image:url('img/myBg.png');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forgot about "Path to URL" transformation and my images was not shown.