# i am trying to upload html page on web view but images are not loading

Tags: ios, uiwebview

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myfile" ofType:@"html"];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"The html string is %@",htmlString);
[_Webview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: try this if you load local image http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747407/using-html-and-local-images-within-uiwebview

Comment: Note: upload tends to mean sent **to** the server. `loadHTMLString:` loads a file **from** the server to the device. You need to update the question. Also where are the images and what is the html that references the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if your html file or string have the url for the image then it will load it automatically you won't have to worry about it. look at your html file and make sure that you get your image url properly in html string.