# Unable to use images from document directory in JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, bing, nsdocumentdirectory

I am storing user specific images getting from server in `document directory`. Then I want to display this images on bing map at certain pins(inside pin InfoBox). I am loading the images dynamically using javaScript. But images are not displaying on map.

I am setting images as HTML content of `infoBox` like,

```
pinInfoBox.setHtmlContent('<div class="arrow_box"><div class="content" id="content"><img id="localFile" src="file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/395E5EED-2FB4-4505-861E-2DA9AB96433B/Documents/my_image.jpg/"/>'+pin.Title+'</div></div>');
```

If I use any remote file and access it via `http protocol` it will work,

```
pinInfoBox.setHtmlContent('<div class="arrow_box"><div class="content" id="content"><img id="localFile" src="http://a.abcd.com/static/images/zoom/magnifying-glass.png" />'+pin.Title+'</div></div>');
```

I don't know why it is not taking image saved in my document directory.

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: have you tried altering the src URL with the localhost directory path  example : `src="localhost:port/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/395E5EED-2FB4-4505-861E-2DA9AB96433B/Documents/my_image.jpg/"`

Comment: @anusha-k I feel like you have 1 missing forward slash and one extra. Change to: ``pinInfoBox.setHtmlContent('<div class="arrow_box"><div class="content" id="content"><img id="localFile" src="file:////var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/395E5EED-2FB4-4505-861E-2DA9AB96433B/Documents/my_image.jpg"/>'+pin.Title+'</div></div>')``.

This example will only work if the image serving page is also opened from file:/// location. When the serving page is opened from url (eg. http://foo.com) this will never work.

Comment: @tiblu I didn't understand. my .js file is in application bundle and and loading dynamically. When desired location information is received, a method in .js file is called with image path(which is in document directory). Is there any problem in that?

Comment: @anusha-k  Try the suggestion above to fix the image source. I added the extra notice just in case. If it is an application bundle, I guess it should be fine. But I lack experience with the bundles.

Comment: @anusha-k Sorry, now when I think about it, maybe ``file:///`` is disabled for a reason. You could possibly reference any another bundles files if it was allowed. Sorry for long-shotting here, but this may be related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747407/using-html-and-local-images-within-uiwebview

Comment: @tiblu Bundle file will work directly with the imageName just like in other objective c file. But this document directory path not working.

Comment: @tiblu Answer was in your `extra notice`. But I can't write images to bundle. So I copy my javaScript file to document directory. Now I can dynamically load image directly specifying its name only. No need of root directory components. Thank you..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this based on @tiblu's comment.

```
JavaScript file and images should be in same path.
```

But I can't write images to bundle as these images are downloaded from server at runtime. So I copied JavaScript file to `documentDirectory` during application launch to work with images. Then we can simply access the image directly with it's name and no need of specifying full path.

```
pinInfoBox.setHtmlContent('<div class="arrow_box"><div class="content" id="content"><img id="localFile" src="my_image.jpg"/>'+pin.Title+'</div></div>');
```