# Working out image path from bundle - Swift

Tags: html, swift

I'm using `let htmllogo = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "logo", ofType: "png")!`
 to try to load up an image in a HTML string.

My image location has been set to relative to group and is shown as being at "logo.png" in my Identity and Type parameters.

This is what my image HTML looks like after getting the location for the image relative to bundle path.

`<img alt="" src="/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F524A7D3-B24A-4353-9A7D-B33321670EC4/ot.app/logo.png">`

I am still getting no image in my HTML. Is my method of getting the image correct - which would mean it's an issue with my WebView?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using HTML and Local Images Within UIWebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747407/using-html-and-local-images-within-uiwebview)