# objective c : Load URL or Local File ( uiwebview)

Tags: objective-c, xcode

how can i open local file (html,jpg...etc ) and website url with same uiwebview

this code worked for website url only

```
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];

[viewWeb loadRequest:request];}
```

or can i use  check if the path input is URL or Local File if yes ? How ?

Comment: Check out UIWebView function - (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(nullable NSURL *)baseURL; also check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/747644/513286

Answer (score 3):

- For an URL with a scheme (e.g.`http://`) use

  ```
  NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver/path/to/file.html"];
  ```
- For a file URL use

  ```
  NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/myUser/path/to/file.html"];
  ```

  or add the scheme

  ```
  NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///Users/myUser/path/to/file.html"];
  ```

A file URL starts always with a slash

```
if ([urlString hasPrefix:@"/"]) {
    // is file URL
} else {
    // is URL including a scheme
}
```