# display image in html in webview from document directory

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, uikit

I would like to display an image in html which is being displayed on a `UIWebView` from the App's Document directory.

Can someone suggest me how to accomplish that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478665/link-to-resources-inside-webview-iphone/1382396#1382396 Here I found the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can help you

[Using HTML and Local Images Within UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747407/using-html-and-local-images-within-uiwebview)

[Link to resources inside WebView - iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478665/link-to-resources-inside-webview-iphone/1382396#1382396)

Answer (score -2):

```
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
   NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
   [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

You can then refer to your images like this:

```
   <img src="myimage.png">
```