# UIWebview - Loading PNG image - got error

Tags: ios

I am trying to load the image(png) in UIWebview. But I got the following error 
""ImageIO:  PNGinvalid literal/lengths set"

I will get the "png" from the web service. I will store it in the following path. "Users/XXX/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/E4DE3097-EA84-492F-A2A7-5882202F3B00/Documents/attachement.png "

When I reading the file from the path, I got the error. I am using the following code

```
  NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle]; 


  NSString *path = [bundle bundlePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

    NSString *commentHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img src=\"%@\"/>", documentEntity.path];
    NSString *html3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head/><body><div><b>COMMENTS:</b></div>%@</body></html>", commentHtml];
    [self.documentView loadHTMLString:html3 baseURL:baseURL];
```

Please help me.

THanks
Girija

Comment: any code will help for better understanding

Comment: As samfisher said, it's hard to help without the code. Also: if you're loading an image from app bundle please upload it to your question; if you're loading it from web please provide a link. Did you try to show the same image in a UIImageView?

Comment: For starters try the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747407/using-html-and-local-images-within-uiwebview (ie: without the extra html). Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808451/how-to-embed-local-images-in-uiwebview, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329648/display-local-uiimage-on-uiwebview also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have saved the Image in Documents Folder, why are you fetching from MainBundle.
Fetching Image from the Documents Directory would be :

```
    NSString *aDocumentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *aFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/attachement.png", aDocumentsDirectory];
    UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:aFilePath];
```

Comment: Hi Thanks.. I am tried the as per your suggestion. But I am getting the error ""ImageIO: PNGinvalid literal/lengths set" and also image won't get loaded. Please help me.. THanks in advance...

Comment: Actullay,  I am getting the image in Base64Encoded format from the service. So again I have converted Base64Decoded then write in the file path.After that I am trying to read the image, I got the error and image did not get loaded...

Comment: once u saved the image in the documents folder, did u check if the image was in the right format ?

Comment: would be helpful if you could post the code that u used to save the image... also, the URL for the Image..