# Adding Image in the UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, uiimageview

I have a `UIWebView` and I am just displaying some text. I am using html text to format the `UIWebView`. How can I include a `image/UIImage` inside it? I need to display an image with a fixed frame.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329648/display-local-uiimage-on-uiwebview

Comment: At least add a title to your question...

Answer (score 5):

Use `img` tag. Inject this in your HTML code & render it in `UIWebView`.

This should help -

```
NSString *html = @"<html><body style='margin:0;'><img width='300' height='300' src='my_test_image.jpg'></body></html>";
[web loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
```