# Where is build output going?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I have a library project in Xcode 4.  I'm building against iOS 4.3.  The build products path is set to /Developer/Projects/BuildOutput.  I'm building 'iPhone 4.3 Simulator'.  In Xcode4, how do you specify a debug or release build?

When I go to /Developer/Projects/BuildOutput/Debug-iphonesimulator, the library .a file is not there.

In the project settings Info tab, 'command line builds use' is set to Debug.  In previous versions of Xcode, debug/release build options were available from the drop down menu on the main IDE toolbar - same location that I'm choosing 'iPhone 4.3 Simulator'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They changed the build behavior in Xcode 4 a little, so builds do not longer end up in the same directories as before.

You can fix this in the Xcode 4 preferences (notice the *Derived Data* setting):

[image: XCode screenshot]

Comment: Nice.  Thanks.  For the above option on Build Location, is that recommended?  Mine is set to the other option, which is working for me.