# Where is the resources folder for my project in Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

When I create a new project in Xcode 4 it does not create the resources folder like Xcode 3 used to do. Is there a setting in Xcode 4 to make this work?

Answer (score 31):

As badcat indicates in his comments, the Resources folder was merely a group within the project template.  To create your own Resources group, either right-click on the project explorer view and choose `New Group`, or go to the menu option `File | New | New Group`.

If you want to make sure that items which should be resources are copied into the correct location in your application bundle, you can click on the name of your project in the project explorer on the left of the screen and go to the `Build Phases` tab.  You can expand the `Copy Bundle Resources` build phase (or whatever it's called in your project) and see the files that will be copied over.  If something is missing, you can drag it into that list from the project explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "Resources" folder, but maybe this answer helps you with that:

- [Where is build output going?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341496/where-is-build-output-going/5342176#5342176)

Comment: The folder that Xcode 3 creates to put nibs and pslist files in the project tree. I think group is the technical term instead of folder..http://i.imgur.com/sIr5Z.png

Comment: Well, create one and drag the NIB files in there? In Xcode it's basically just a group and is separate from the actual file system - so the file is not being moved. The Resources folder was part of a code template in Xcode 3.

Comment: Thank you. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question if you don't just want the *group* but also the physical *folder* on your filesystem: [How do I get the resources folder back in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789223/how-do-i-get-the-resources-folder-back-in-xcode-4)