# Difference between the UIWebView methods loadHTMLString: and loadRequest

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a UIWebView and I want to load an SVG image into it. The contents of the file is pure SVG i.e. `<svg>...</svg>`. The file loads fine into normal and Mobile Safari, and also in a UIWebView using loadRequest: by doing the following:

```
url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:req];
```

However, if I load the contents of the file into a string, and try to load the HTML string into the webview, nothing displays:

```
html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                   error:nil];
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Is there any reason between the above two techniques? Should they not give the same results? The file is pure ASCII, so I don't think there is an encoding issue.

I guess I can get what I need done right now by using a file, but I hate to use the filesystem for non persistent data.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks,
Ron

Comment: Could the problem be that my "html" is not really html? My file begins and ends with '<svg> ... </svg>'. Is it possible that loading a request handles non-HTML files, while loadHTMLString requires the text to be HTML?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To solve this issue you have to use `loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:` instead.

```
NSData *data = [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"application/xhtml+xml" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:baseUrl];
```

Comment: I used MIMEType "text/html" since xhtml+xml is strict and will cause rendering errors if the html isn't perfect (i.e. all tags must be closed properly, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this but if the `baseURL` is set to nil, I think the webview does not know from where to load the contents.

Hope this SO question helps u [Link to resources inside WebView - iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478665/link-to-resources-inside-webview-iphone)

Comment: Thanks for the information! In my case, however, I don't think that is what is causing the problem since the HTML is completely self contained.