# Failed to load large image in UI Webview ios

Tags: iphone, ios, image, memory, uiwebview

I am working on an iPhone/iPad application. Trying to load very large image in UIImage view stored in local directory in app. Code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:selectedImage ofType:@"jpg"];
NSString *cssString = @"<style type='text/css'>img {width: 100%; height: auto;} body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }</style>";
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head>%@</head><body><img src=\"file://%@\" /></body></html>",cssString,path];
[webview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

In iPhone and Simulator images gets loaded perfectly but when I try to run app in iPod touch 4g it misses the image in UI Webview. I guess there are some memory issues. Not sure.
Any help.

Image size is: 640*5000

Comment: make sure the name of image is same which you added in your project bundle bcz Simulator is not case-sensitive..

Comment: not that's no the issue. Iphone 4 loads perfectly. Problem is only with iPod

Answer (score 0):

may be this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478665/link-to-resources-inside-webview-iphone/1382396#1382396) or [link2](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/uiwebview-revisited) will help you

We tried with the code and its working,

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"imageName" ofType:@"png"];
       NSString *_path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
          NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:_path];
      [self.webobj loadData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile ath] MIMEType:@"image/png" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:baseURL];
```